# Can you call a function that returns in the context of the caller?

Tags: javascript, php, python, stack, return

I don't think this is possible, but hey you never know. I'm curious if this is possible to do in common languages. My examples will be in JavaScript, but I'd be curious to know if this can be done in Python, PHP, Java, etc.

Let's say there are two functions.

```
var printX = function(x){
    checkX(x, this);
    console.log(x);
}
var checkX = function(x, caller){
    if (x > 10){
        caller.return;
    }
}
printX(5);  //Prints 5
printX(15); //Doesn't print anything
```

**Obviously there are much better ways of expressing this**, I'd just like to know if the concept is possible.

Comment: no, you can only `return` inside a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, if you want to stop the code that called your function, you throw an exception:

```js
var printX = function(x) {
    checkX(x);
    document.write(x);
}
var checkX = function(x) {
    if (x > 10) {
        throw "exit";
    }
}

try { printX(5)  } catch(e) {}  
try { printX(15) } catch(e) {}
```

Comment: Right, I know that's the proper way to do it. I just wanted to know if the other way was possible. Thanks.